# The generics which derived from non generics in c#

Tags: c#, class, generics

I have a design question:

I have the Fabric class and it works really well, but I need to add Generic functionality to the Fabric class. The usage at below is correct? Or what could be the best solution adding generic functionality to non generic. By the way I want to keep using non generic class is methods.

Fabric class:

```
public class Fabric
{
    public Fabric DoJob(string entityName)
    {
        //entityName is table name in database
        //do some job with entityName and
        return this;
    }

}

public class Fabric<T> : Fabric where T : Entity
{
    public Fabric<T> DoJob(T entity)
    {
        DoJob(typeof(T).Name); 
        //Do job comes from base class and it waits entity name so I am sending it from T
        return this;

    }
}
```

Comment: You're asking if this usage is correct, but how could we possibly tell without knowing what the functionality is supposed to be? On the surface though, it looks wrong because (I am guessing) that you want to return the result of `DoJob` but you cannot cast a `Fabric` to a `Fabric<T>`

Comment: Hi DavidG, I wont return DoJob is result. The DoJob method will do some work and I will return Fabric<T> again. I edited the question.

Comment: Why would the DoJob methods need to return `this` (instead of being `void` methods)?

Comment: @elgonzo A fluent interface?

Comment: @Abdulkadir But we still don't know what the intent of this code is, so it's impossible to answer. This isn't a good question for SO I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't know what your end goal is, but based on the code in your question, instead of introducing a generic Fabric<T> type, you could alternatively create a generic extension DoJob method using the Fabric type. (I am not recommending one approach over the other. I am just showing possibly possible alternatives)

Comment: It returns this because fluent interface. Explaining is really hard, sorry for question guys.

Comment: @Abdulkadir, don't worry. I know what fluent interfaces are, my brain is just not in prime condition. (With the debugger tools i have at hand the fluent approach really likes to get into the way when i want to do "step over", "step over", "step into" and forces me to manually navigate source code and tell the debugger "execute to cursor position", so i really try my best to ignore (extensive) fluent approach as best as i can ;-) Not sure if the debugger in VS2017 has been improved in this respect or not)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, code is correct. Deriving generic from non-generic base class is quite a standard practice. Sharing common name is also fine (see `Task`/`Task<T>` classes for example).

Whether such hierarchy suits your needs is up to you to decide.

Comment: Hi Alexei, this is what I am trying to do. Do you have more examples for understanding how generic class implements non generic class is methods?

Comment: @Abdulkadir no idea what you are asking, sorry. Derived classes don't "implement" base class' methods - they are just available from derived class...